# Zero knowledge proof for a discrete logarithm

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, discrete-logarithm

Say a have a group $G$ chosen as $Z_N^*$ where $N=pq$ and both $p$ and $q$ are safe primes. The algorithm for discrete logarithm is as follows:

1. Pick $g$ as a random element from $Z_N^*$
2. Pick $x$ as a random element from $(0, N')$ where ${N' =  p' q'}$ where ${p=2p' + 1}$ and ${q=2q' + 1}$
3. Evaluate ${y = g^x \: mod \: N}$

For public $y$ and $g$, what is the easiest way to construct ZKP that the prover knows $x$ without revealing it?

Comment: As far as I know, the Schnorr protocol is proven to be honest-verifier zero-knowledge but not zero-knowledge and my understanding of this fact is that dishonest verifier can learn about the secret. Isn't that a case?

Comment: "Any" (means "not honest") verifier would make simulator fail to produce expected output, but not learn about the secret.

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych Interesting, can you please look at [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/61771/59088) and shed some light on it?

Comment: If I recall correctly, can we not use the Fiat Shamir transform on the Schnorr protocol to make it full ZK (as Schnorr is a Sigma protocol)?

Answer (score 3):

This problem was studied in [BCK], and interestingly they showed that constructing a Schnorr-like zero-knowledge proof system (ZKP) in a group of *unknown order* with non-trivial soundness error is *not* possible in the plain model (i.e., without [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_reference_string_model)). Their result is much more general and talks about homomorphisms in groups of unknown order.

However, if one considers the CRS model, then [BBF] recently showed that ZKP is possible in the [generic group model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_group_model) under the "adaptive root" assumption. Boneh talks briefly about this work [here](https://youtu.be/wB3DlND7KEw?t=660).

[BBF]: Boneh, Bünz and Fisch, *[Batching Techniques for Accumulators with Applications to IOPs and Stateless Blockchains](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1188)*, Crypto 2019

[BCK]: Bangerter, Camenisch and Krenn, *[Efficiency Limitations for Σ-Protocols for Group Homomorphisms](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-11799-2_33)*, TCC 2010

Comment: Great and correct answer! Instead of Knowledge of Exponent assumption, did not you want to say Adaptive Root assumption?

Comment: Good point. In the talk Boneh mentions knowledge-of-exponent assumption, but looking at the paper again, it seems they rely on the adaptive root assumption.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple example of full ZKPoK of discrete log, you can look into this paper http://www.cs.au.dk/~ivan/Sigma.pdf of Damgard.
In a chapter "8 Zero-Knowledge from Σ-protocols" it constructs a full ZK protocol,
which is just a bit more complicated than Schnorr one.

Comment: Dåmgard's assumption is over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ with $q$ prime though, I think the answer to this question should also address what happens over $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$.