# Honest players in ZKP proofs

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Trying to study ZKPs, I have seen that proofs qualify players (a part from -of course- simulator and extractor): so honest prover, honest verifier.

Is it needed because usually examples deal with interactive schemas which require players to act in specific ways (so it's not needed when Fiat-Shamir heuristic is used on sigma-protocols to get non-interactive flavours)? Or are there more technical, subtle reasons?

Thanks!

Comment: a self-follow-up regarding role of Fiat-Shamir heuristic in bypassing the honest verifier requirement. Reading first comment and Matthew Green reply [here](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2017/01/21/zero-knowledge-proofs-an-illustrated-primer-part-2/) it seems a possible way paid by ROM introduction

Answer (score 1):

In the example you mentioned, you must have an honest verifier, because a dishonest verifier would be able to extract the witness ([see](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61771/practical-consequences-of-a-honest-verifier-zero-knowledge-of-the-schnorr-protoc?rq=1)).

It is important to remark that there are transformations from honest to dishonest protocols, therefore studying honest protocols makes sense in practice. You may find [this](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Eavi/PUBLICATIONS/ABSTRACT/dgow95.pdf) useful.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got the point: if simulator requires an honest verifier (like Schnorr), if the verifier isn't honest we miss the ZK proof. However I find one of first examples in the provided link not completely satisfying: I mean, I can take *any* ZK proof and add an initial round as suggested, but it seems an artificial and not general way to construct a schema extracting witness starting form an HVZKP: it seems to me that the dishonest acting should be enough, without requiring a modified proof (if initial round is necessary doesn't it mean the original ZKP was dishonesty-resistant?)